# Where to see out put of Print_r() in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

i am learning codeigniter and i use methods(functions) in model to get data from the database. i am not sure whether my method is fetching correct data i want to use print_r(); exit; to debug but do not know where and how to see the output. can any one help me

for example my method in a model is

```
    public function get_price($check)
   {

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('name', $check);
    $this->db->from('group_test');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    print_r($query); exit;
    return $query->result();
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function is fine. The only change you need to do is use print_r function as below

```
public function get_price($check)
   {

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('name', $check);
    $this->db->from('group_test');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    print_r($query->result());
    //return $query->result();
   }
```

So the above code will print the result as an array of objects. Let me know if you want anything else.

Comment: my question was where to see output i am using chrome can i see its output in its developer tool console as the view does not show.

Comment: yes i am seeing the output as an array of objects in console as i am using ajax but unable to get as 'var price = data[0]['price']; ' in ajax query

Comment: Because you are using ajax using `print_r` isn't very useful because it is designed to output to the screen. We would need to see code that is returning data to the browser and the function that handles the ajax response to offer better advice.

Comment: @ieesab It would be better if you show your javascript codes as well to help us debug your problem

Comment: thanks for your help actually i was using autocomplete and when ever i clicked on the suggestion to fill the input box this was generating blank array and when i was pressing enter key instead of mouse it was giving proper json data. Now i can get the price field autofilled.